# I'm having a problem in deleting rows from several tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to delete all the rows which have productid = 'value' from several tables so I tried to join between them but gives me an error

> sql command not properly ended

so I was asking if this could actually work and if not can anyone tell me how should I do such a thing?

```
    DELETE FROM 
      products, products_admin, products_category, products_seller, categories
    USING 
      products 
    JOIN 
      products_admin ON products_admin.productid = products.productid 
    JOIN 
      products_category ON products_category.productid = products.productid 
    JOIN
      products_seller on products_seller.productid = products.productid
    JOIN 
      categories on categories.productsid = products.productid
    WHERE 
      products.productid = 'value';
```

[here's what I tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSmCI.jpg)

Comment: One `DELETE` per table is needed.

Comment: Like this? DELETE FROM TABLE_1 WHERE column1 = 'abc';
DELETE FROM TABLE_2 WHERE column1 = 'abc';
DELETE FROM TABLE_3 WHERE column1 = 'abc';
DELETE FROM TABLE_4 WHERE column1 = 'abc';

Comment: Isn't that will execute only the first one?

Comment: @Maha as Jarlh has said, you need a delete statement per table in Oracle. You would need to then run each one, making sure that you run the deletes for child tables first before their parent tables if there are foreign keys in place.

Comment: Or parents first, if there are _on delete cascade_ fk's.

Comment: @Boneist excuse my silliness please. I tried what you and Jarlh said making sure to delete from child tables first and selected all the statements to run them (execute them) but it was executed for the first table only :/

Comment: How were you executing them? Via a script in SQL*Plus? One at a time in Toad? something else?

Comment: @Boneist I attached a picture.... I click on the green button on the left

Comment: There should be an option to run as a script (which would run all the statements) - it’s possibly the second icon in? You may or may not need to highlight all the statements you want to run first.

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

If you have foreign keys defined with `ON DELETE CASCADE`, deleting from products table will delete records from all associated tables. See https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/foreign_keys/foreign_delete.php

Comment: unfortunately it's not on delete cascade :(

Comment: @Maha: then, as others noted, you need to delete records from dependent tables first using one delete per table before you are able to delete from the main table. Or you can update table definitions to include `ON DELETE CASCADE`